# Why design the reincarnated HMS Hood to be able to fly?

Tags: politics, technological-development, airships, shipbuilding

It has been almost a century since the pride of the British navy was sunk by the greatest threat to the allies that ever floated. The fateful day came when a plunging shell from Bismarck exploded the weapon magazine inside the HMS Hood. The event sent shock wave throughout the colonies' media worldwide: the admiral-class battleship, once thought to be unsinkable, was lost in the Denmark Strait. Don't worry... the fans worked tirelessly around the clock and eventually tracked it down and finally avenged the late Hood. The rest is history.

I shall cut to the chase: the British Empire decides to compete for sea dominance after Brexit causes it to hemorrhage heavily, both financially and politically. The British must recover their lost pride by constructing a state-of-the-art, heavily armed fortress that can scare the wits out of its adversary. One question: why must it have to fly?

I shall urge everyone to resist the temptation to discuss the technology behind the new man-made wonder of the world, if you must please use magic sparingly.

Comment: Something that lifts 47.430 tons of steel?

Comment: Btw: Are you asking Why someone should make a century old ship fly or are you asking What does it take to make it fly?

Comment: @Alexander von Wenherr: that's correct! Why must it have to be flying? That my question...

Comment: Just to give you an idea, what you're asking: The almighty AN-225 weights only 175 tons. We're talking about a factor 271 here.

Comment: @Alexander von Wernherr: 100 years after the battle of Denmark Strait(1941) pretty much sufficient time for lightweight material and revolution in shipbuilding to take place think big think ridiculously BIG my mate!

Comment: This question was extremely hard to parse. I cleaned up the grammar, but next time I'll probably just vote to close as "unclear". Please double check that the question still says what you intended it to say.

Comment: HMS Hood was built in 1916-1918, and then was one of the most powerful warships in the world. In 1941 was scheduled for a major rebuild, specially the gunnery that was outdated. Nobody ever thought of HMS as "unsinkable", it was indeed the proud of the Royal Navy, but why anyone would like to rebuild HMS Hood these days?

Comment: @roetnig: if it had chosen to abort the idea of crippling the allies supply and head to a friendly dock just hours away things might turned out very different today! BTW I root for Bismarck! I think the German might consider regaining back their lost pride too...

Comment: This endevor makes no sense from any point of view. As a military application, it would be easy to detect and shoot down using much cheaper weapons (missiles). As a means of intimidating its enemies .. which might those be? ISIS? They're holding their own against the Syrian army and Russia, _one flying ship_ is not going to scare them. The rest of Europe, their modern day allies? So then why the heck would you want to sink money into a project which will bring no economic benefit to your struggling country? Ships are of some limited use, but flying ships are a waste of money and time.

Comment: HMS Hood died because of flaws in her design. HMS Hood sank in just three minutes, the same way in 1916 HMS invincible, HMS Queen Mary and HMS Indefatigable were lost in the Battle of Jutland. HMS Hood as a flying object ? Why ? If I could lift 46 thousand tons of weapon in the air I would choose a completely different approach.

Comment: @AndreiROM: time will tell...

Comment: BTW, my grandfather was one of the 1418 that went with the Hood the 24th of May 1941.

Answer (score 2):

I think technology has moved past the days of sea dominance via big ships.  Planes made ship to ship battles nearly obsolete and drones will be the end of them.  So why make the Hood fly, you ask?

1. Option 1 - noncombat reason.  Perhaps public relations.  The Hood will be painted with the Union Jack and fly around the UK as a symbol of Britain Resurgent. Guns could fire candy and chocolates.
2. Option 2 - technology change makes flying fortress sensible.  Perhaps planes themselves are the victims of drones but a monster like the Hood can withstand whatever a puny drone can dish out.  Maybe the drones are autonomous and small and people need somewhere armored to hide.

I humbly suggest the Hood be lifted by fusion powered ramjets that run on air?  That way, for either scenario, when the Hood comes around it will have big flaming rockets that go BWAAAAAAA.

Answer (score 1):

*this was written before the magic part in the OP*

Sorry, but... you don't.

An Airship one would consider as a fortress is heavy and needs uplift.

HMS Hood weighted 47.430 tons. Lets take it as a starting point.

The Hindenburg balloon took 190.000 m³ Hydrogen and was able to lift 242 tons.
To lift the Hood, you'd need 200 times more Hydrogen (at least), which is 38000000m³ of Hydrogen.

Even if you'd manage to lift it, it will be extremely sluggish and would need bigger engines than currently available.

So, this is a No. Not feasible, not practical, not anything but a good targeting practise for attackers.

Answer (score 0):

It is a non-violent demonstration of an overwhelming shift in the balance of power.  If the British can make a ship of that size fly, then their technology (or magic) is centuries ahead of every other nation in the world.

The Empire is reborn and all the world, once again, fears the mighty Hood.

Comment: I like ur answer however I'm troubled by a certain tone that you used, care to explain what's so magical about the mighty Hood?

Comment: It is not the Hood which is magical.  It is the ability to make a battleship fly.  By our current understanding of physics and the limits of any fuel's power to weight ratio, lifting a battleship into the air under its own power is simply impossible.  Anyone who could do it using today's technology would either know something that no one else does, or would be guilty of witchcraft.